# Check if wallet has NFT

Tags: web3js, wallets, javascript, nft

I am trying to check if a certain wallet has an NFT from a contract.

I am using the following libraries:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@walletconnect/browser@1.0.0-beta.46/lib/index.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@walletconnect/qrcode-modal@1.0.0-beta.46/lib/index.min.js"></script><!--
```

I tried the following:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    var WalletConnect = window.WalletConnect.default;
    var WalletConnectQRCodeModal = window.WalletConnectQRCodeModal.default;

    // Display all
    var displayData = async function (payload) { 
        console.log("connected")
        console.log(payload)


        let icyContract = "0x37d754D6D1668e32678fbeb2604Da9CB4fBe993F"
        let response = await fetch('./icyfounderclub_abi.json')
        let abiRes = await response.json();
        let abi = JSON.parse(abiRes["result"])

        let walletAddress = "";
        if (typeof payload === 'undefined') {
            walletAddress = "0x26195376410c52c9622037250d070a19ef04e513";
        } else {
            walletAddress = payload["params"][0]["accounts"][0];
        }
        const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)      
        
        const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, icyContract)
        contract.defaultAccount = walletAddress

        // get balance of how many nfts you have
        const balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress).call() // <--- Here I get the error!!!

        console.log(balance)

        for(let i = 0; i < balance; i++) {
            const tokenId = await contract.methods.tokenOfOwnerByIndex(walletAddress, i).call()
        
            let tokenMetadataURI = await contract.methods.tokenURI(tokenId).call()

            if(tokenMetadataURI.startsWith("ipfs://")) {
                tokenMetadataURI = `https://ipfs.io/ipfs${tokenMetadataURI.split("ipfs://")[1]}`
            }

            const tokenMetadata = await fetch(tokenMetadata).then((response) => response.json())
            console.log(tokenMetadata["image"])

        }
    }


    // Get an instance of the WalletConnect connector
    var walletConnector = new WalletConnect({
        bridge: 'https://bridge.walletconnect.org' // Required
    });

    // Display data if connected
    if (walletConnector.connected) {
        displayData();
    }

    // When the connect/disconnect button is clicked
    connect = function () { // Check if connection is already established
        if (! walletConnector.connected) { // create new session
            walletConnector.createSession().then(() => { // get uri for QR Code modal
                var uri = walletConnector.uri;
                // display QR Code modal
                WalletConnectQRCodeModal.open(uri, () => {
                    console.log('QR Code Modal closed');
                });
            });
        } else { // disconnect
                walletConnector.killSession();
        }
    }

    // Subscribe to connection events: connect, session_update and disconnect
    walletConnector.on('connect', function (error, payload) {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        } else { // Close QR Code Modal
            WalletConnectQRCodeModal.close();
            // connection is made so we can display all the data
            displayData(payload);
        }
    });

    walletConnector.on('session_update', function (error, payload) {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        } else if (walletConnector.connected) { // data may be changed
            displayData();
        }

    });

    walletConnector.on('disconnect', function (error, payload) {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        } else {
            // remove all the data
        }
    });
});
```

This is the contract I am checking against: https://etherscan.io/address/0x37d754d6d1668e32678fbeb2604da9cb4fbe993f#code

Here I get the error:

```
  const balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress).call()
```

This is the error:

```
Uncaught Error Error: Provider not set or invalid
    at InvalidProvider (/home/myProject/packages/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:39:16)
    at c.send (/home/myProject/packages/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:145:32)
    at c (/home/myProject/packages/web3-core-method/lib/index.js:629:42)
    at n (/home/myProject/packages/web3-core-method/lib/index.js:661:13)
    at y._executeMethod (/home/myProject/packages/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:810:20)
    at eval (<eval>/VM46947625:1:43)
    at displayData (/home/myProject/script.js:33:40)
    --- setTimeout ---
    at _fireError (/home/myProject/packages/web3-utils/lib/index.js:63:9)
    at a (/home/myProject/packages/web3-core-method/lib/index.js:553:30)
    at c.send (/home/myProject/packages/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:145:16)
    at c (/home/myProject/packages/web3-core-method/lib/index.js:629:42)
    at n (/home/myProject/packages/web3-core-method/lib/index.js:661:13)
    at y._executeMethod (/home/myProject/packages/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:810:20)
    at eval (<eval>/VM46947625:1:43)
    at displayData (/home/myProject/script.js:33:40)
    --- await ---
    at <anonymous> (/home/myProject/script.js:69:9)
Uncaught Error Error: Provider not set or invalid
    at InvalidProvider (/home/myProject/packages/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:39:16)
    at c.send (/home/myProject/packages/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:145:32)
    at c (/home/myProject/packages/web3-core-method/lib/index.js:629:42)
    at n (/home/myProject/packages/web3-core-method/lib/index.js:661:13)
    at y._executeMethod (/home/myProject/packages/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:810:20)
    at displayData (/home/myProject/script.js:33:73)
    --- await ---
    at <anonymous> (/home/myProject/script.js:69:9)
```

I tried setting the provider the following:        `const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)`

However this does not seem to work.

Any suggestions why I get this error?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it helps you but i use this code on javascript to NFT balances and tokenID's ownded by an address:

```
//A RETURN FUNCTION OR AN API MIDDLEWARE
    const balance = await erc721.balanceOf(walletAddress);


    const getTokensId = async (recipient, index) => {
        try {
            const result = nonfungibleManager.tokenOfOwnerByIndex(recipient, index);
            return result;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error, "the error for getTokensId");
        }
    };

    const getPosition = async (id) => {
        try {
            const position = erc721.positions(id);
            return position;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error, "error from getPosition");
        }
    };

    let nfts = [];

    let numbers = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < Number(balance._hex); i++) {
        numbers.push(i);
    }
    await Promise.all(
        numbers.map(async (i) => {
            await getTokensId(walletAddress, i).then(async (res) => {
                let tokenId = Number(res?._hex);
                await getPosition(tokenId).then((result) => {
                    nfts.push({
                        'tokenId': tokenId
                    });
                });
            });
        })
    );

return nfts

//END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the [getWalletNFTs](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/reference/get-wallet-nfts) endpoint provided by Moralis. You will get all the NFTs owned by a wallet address.

Here is an example of how to implement this step by step https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/how-to-get-all-nfts-owned-by-an-address

Let me know if you need any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the following to inject a dedicated web3js object and use that to send transactions.

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
    if (window.ethereum) {
        await window.ethereum.enable();
        window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);    
        const txn = window.web3.eth.sendTransaction([PARAMS]);
    }
```

Comment: I do not want to send a trx, I just want to check the balanceOf a wallet address. In my code I already injected `new Web3(window.ethereum);  `

Comment: I mean you have the object you can refer to and use it to send any specific requests. So create a contract object and try interaction with it?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).